# Install-SPUserSolution: Sandboxed code execution request failed

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

When executing **Install-SPUserSolution** powershell command the following error is shown:

> Install-SPUserSolution : Sandboxed code execution request failed.
>   At line:1 char:23
>   + Install-SPUserSolution <<<<  -Identity some_package.wsp -Site `http://localhost/sites/test`
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...allUserSolution:
>      SPCmdletInstallUserSolution) [Install-SPUserSolution], SPUserCodeExecu...F
>     ailedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletInstallU
>      serSolution

When I try to activate the user solution from the SharePoint interface everything works fine. So this doesn't work only from PowerShell. I tried to run user code service under different account (admin account) but this didn't help. Currently this service is running under Network Service account.

Also when I run Add-SPUserSolution or Uninstall-SPUserSolution they work just fine. I was able to reproduce this issue on at least two servers. Please advice.

**[UPD]** I'm including full stack trace from SharePoint logs

> Sandboxed code execution request failed. - Inner Exception: System.InvalidOperationException    Server stack trace:      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.Verify.DoFailTag(UInt32 tag, ULSCat category, Type type, String format, Object[] args)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.Verify.IsTrueTag(UInt32 tag, ULSCat category, Boolean expression, Type type, String format, Object[] args)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionHost.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String affinity, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPUserCodeExecutionHostProxy.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String affinityBucketName, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionManager.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPSite site, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)

Comment: There should be something more in SharePoint logs. And there is one more idea - can you verify if your Alternate Access Mappings are properly configured for http://localhost ?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you with localhost. I modified it for this question. The URL contains PC name instead. Also I checked the LOGS and found that Inner Exception says Exception occurred while installing feature _[GUID]_: Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionPipelineFailedException: Sandboxed code execution request failed. ---> System.InvalidOperationException. There is a feature receiver for that feature but I don't use anything which is not allowed in a sandboxed.

Comment: Maybe somewhere in FeatureEventReceiver, on Activation, you're referencing to `SPContext.Current`, or something similar, that is not available, if code is not running from webbrowser? Can you also post full stacktrace? I don't expect to much from it (cause this `SPUserCodeExecutionPipelineFailedException` is quite generic and doesn't say to much, but this might be a start.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies Marek. I can add and activate this WSP through the SharePoint interface so I think if it was a forbidden code issue then SharePoint would throw this exception in either case. Am I right? And I modified the question to include full stack trace.

Comment: At this point I'm out of ideas. In most cases there should be something more in logs, at least i always had. What your code in `FeatureEventReceiver` is doing?

Comment: I tested with the brand new wsp which has only content type definition and it worked using powershell. Then I added just an Event Receiver with all methods commented and the powershell failed. So probably there should be some attribute or something on the event receiver. What do you think?